# Drag and Drop Matching Type game with groupings in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

sorry for the misunderstandings in my program, i'm quite new here and i am also new in using flash. here is the sample output that i used in my code

![sample output(http://i1114.photobucket.com/albums/k532/deadmaster2903/sample.jpg)

---

and here is the code i used:

```
 var objectoriginalX:Number;
 var objectoriginalY:Number;
 var score:Number = 0;
 var count:Number = 30;
 var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,count);
 myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
 myTimer.start();
 if (myText_txt.text == "0")
 {
myText_txt.text ="Times Up!";
 }
 function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void
 {
myText_txt.text = String((count)-myTimer.currentCount);
 }
 //fall
 fallapple_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallapple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallapple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallchicory_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallchicory_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallchicory_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallchilipeppers_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallchilipeppers_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallchilipeppers_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallchinesecabbage_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallchinesecabbage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallchinesecabbage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallcranberries_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallcranberries_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallcranberries_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallcucumber_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallcucumber_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallcucumber_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 falldates_mc.buttonMode = true;
 falldates_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 falldates_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallgrapes_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallgrapes_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallgrapes_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallleaflettuce_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallleaflettuce_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallleaflettuce_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallnuts_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallnuts_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallnuts_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallpersimmon_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallpersimmon_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallpersimmon_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 fallpomegranates_mc.buttonMode = true;
 fallpomegranates_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 fallpomegranates_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 //spring
 springasparagus_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springasparagus_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springasparagus_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springbasil_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springbasil_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springbasil_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springbeans_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springbeans_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springbeans_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springbeets_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springbeets_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springbeets_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springberries_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springberries_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springberries_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springiceberg_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springiceberg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springiceberg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springmango_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springmango_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springmango_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springpapaya_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springpapaya_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springpapaya_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springpeas_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springpeas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springpeas_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springradish_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springradish_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springradish_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springrhubarb_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springrhubarb_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springrhubarb_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 springshallots_mc.buttonMode = true;
 springshallots_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 springshallots_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 //summer
 summerapricot_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerapricot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerapricot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerbellpepper_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerbellpepper_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerbellpepper_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerbrocolli_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerbrocolli_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerbrocolli_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summercherries_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summercherries_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summercherries_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summercorn_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summercorn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summercorn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerfigs_mc.buttonMode = true;  
 summerfigs_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerfigs_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerokra_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerokra_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerokra_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerpeaches_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerpeaches_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerpeaches_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerplum_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerplum_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerplum_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summersquash_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summertomato_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summertomato_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summertomato_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 summerwatermelon_mc.buttonMode = true;
 summerwatermelon_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 summerwatermelon_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 //winter
 winteravocado_mc.buttonMode = true;
 winteravocado_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 winteravocado_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 winterbrusselsprouts_mc.buttonMode = true;
 winterbrusselsprouts_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 winterbrusselsprouts_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 wintercabbage_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintercabbage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintercabbage_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 wintercauliflower_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintercauliflower_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintercauliflower_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 winterceleryroots_mc.buttonMode = true;
 winterceleryroots_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 winterceleryroots_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 winterfennel_mc.buttonMode = true;
 winterfennel_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 winterfennel_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 wintergrapefruit_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintergrapefruit_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintergrapefruit_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 wintermandarin_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintermandarin_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintermandarin_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 wintermushrooms_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintermushrooms_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintermushrooms_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 winterpears_mc.buttonMode = true;
 winterpears_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 winterpears_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 winterspinach_mc.buttonMode = true;
 winterspinach_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 winterspinach_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
 wintersquash_mc.buttonMode = true;
 wintersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
 wintersquash_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

 function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
event.target.startDrag(true);
event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
response_txt.text = " ";
 }
 function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
event.target.stopDrag();
var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
{
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
    event.target.buttonMode = false;
    event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
    event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
    response_txt.text = "You did it!";
    score++;
    scoreField.text = String(score);
}
else
{
    event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
    event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
    response_txt.text = "Try again";
}
 };
```

---

so from what i have said before, if you could see the gray boxes and are named with their specified type, that is the dog/cat box i was referring to before. and the images above are the kinds i was talking to

---

so the problem were as you could see in the image, the chicory vegetables is placed under the fall (where it belongs to) in the 2nd box, from the code reference i have seen, they do it this way.

**OBJECT** which is the item is only equal to 1 **CONTAINER** which is the box

i kept on searching for ways that will let 1 image if dragged and dropped to the specified group types, it will be correct (even if yo place it on the 1st box, the image will automatically be in the 2nd box if the group is true)

also, i noticed my timer isn't working, and the text that states whether the answer is true or false produces wrong or incomplete output. if you see *ou i it* that was what im referring to which is supposed to be *you did it*

thanks for those who will answer. im still searching for solutions but i cant seem to find the same problem that i am having

Comment: I understood nearly nothing. What is the precise technical problem?

Comment: sorry if it was confusing. i don't know how to call the problem so i defined it.but i think the problem in my game is that every time you drag an object into a box in a group,even if the answer is correct, the program see it as wrong. i noticed that an object must be dragged in the the specific box. example: apple object-must be dragged to the applebox and only that. but that is not i want. i tried searching for answers but most samples shows a "one object one box" just like the one i'm using now.

Comment: the bigger an essay you write the less answers you will get. Unless it's code, in there good programmers can find little bugs for you even in hundreds of lines (we know where to look). I don't have the time/willpower to decipher your essay. Do this and you'll get an answer in 30 minutes of posting: make 2 graphics, first one contains the dragable and dragged groups and any other information neccessary for the *correct* and *wrong* actions (how to decide which is which). The second should contain clear examples of how to guess right and wrong (and possibly a small "why" if it's needed). Cheers

Comment: i forgot to mention to post the images to an image hosting service (google "image hosting", for example imageshack) and then edit your answer here and add those things. This essay coupled with graphics should net you an asnwer...

Comment: i am not familiar with inserting images yet, but the link i inserted is the image output of my code, hope it helps. thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to answer this question as you're not showing us any code, therefore I'll answer it with the concept I think is correct.

If I understood you correctly, you have a hierarchy of concepts, that is, first there is dog, then there is Golden Retrievers and Labrador, and the same for cats. You need to organize your code or your graphics, in a way that the Labrador and Golden Retriever are "sons" of Dog, that way it is very easy to verify if they're a dog or not. You can do this either with hierarchy (super and sub classes), or by making the Labrador box a son of the Dog box, that is, the .parent of the Labrador box will point to the Dog box.

If you need a better answer, you'll have to elaborate more on your question, either by showing us some code or how your .fla is organized and how you're verifying things.

Comment: i have posted the codes of my program i hope you could still help me

Answer (score 0):

OK.

Here is what I think you want:

Make a Fruit go into "Fall" group, but whatever gray box you place it on (inside "Fall"), make that specific fruit always drop itself to box #2 (second box in the top row)

Here is how to attempt to do that (these are code snipets):

```
fallapple_mc.buttonMode = true;
fallapple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
fallapple_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
fallapple_mc.droppedGroupName = "Fall"; //I can't use the fallapple_mc.name, since it's "fallapple_mc", not the group name that I want so I have to input the required value manually into this variable
fallapple_mc.droppedBoxIndex = 2; // here I manually input the correct box index for the group
```

Now that the required data is setup, you have to change the dropObject function a little bit (and a few other things, more about that later):

```
function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    //CHANGES BELLOW
    //var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target["droppedGroupName"]; //dynamic access to a variable (the []s) to stop the compiler from being annoying for you...
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if (event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
    {
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        //CHANGES BELLOW
        //event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        //event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.getChildByName("box"+event.target["droppedBoxIndex"]).x; //Here getChild returned the *correct box* so i use it's x and y to position it (might be off a little)! 
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.getChildByName("box"+event.target["droppedBoxIndex"]).y; 
        response_txt.text = "You did it!";
        score++;
        scoreField.text = String(score);
     }
     else
     {
        event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
        event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
        response_txt.text = "Try again";
     }
 };
```

Prerequisites:

1) Above changes will **fail** if you do not change **instance names** of the *Fall group* movieclip to "targetFall".

2) Above will **fail** if **inside** movieclip 'targetFall' you do not make the **boxes** (movieclips) have **instance names** on them. Those boxes need to have instance names like "box1", "box2", "box3" etc in order for this code to function.

That should give you something rudimentary to start to toy with... **expect** this code to fail, I am programming blind, but it's close to how it should look so trace trace trace variables and their values or debug debug debug the #### out of this until you get it to work...

If you get stuck, feel free to ask for clarifications/help in the comments of this answer...